# Magento2 : When making configurations options in configurable product sku undefined

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

When I add configurations to a configurable product the options get the sku undefined+attribute and not the name or sku of the configurable product. See screenshot below

Magento version: 2.1.10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have disabled the "SKU" field and this was the problem

If you look into the `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/variations.js::getProductValue()` there is a selector with `:enabled` prop.

I fixed this by writing mixin in my custom module

app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/variations/variations': {
                'MyCompany_MyModule/js/variations/variations': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/variations.js:

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'jquery'
    ],
    function (Component, $) {
        'use strict';
        return function (Variations) {
            return Variations.extend(
                {
                    /**
                     * @param {String} name
                     * @return {String|Number|Array}
                     */
                    getProductValue: function (name) {
                        name = name.split('/').join('][');

                        return $('[name="product[' + name + ']"]:not(.ignore-validate)', this.productForm).val();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```